# persist multipleChoices checklist on AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I'm working with an alertdialog with multiplechoices. and I want to store the selected values so when the user comes back to the alertdialog, the values he selected previously are still checked. My code :

```
public class TimelineSettings extends DialogFragment {

final ArrayList selected_categories = new ArrayList();
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor;
final CharSequence[]items = {"Fourniture","Nourriture","Voyages","Habillement","MÃ©dias","Autres"};
boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[items.length];
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle("Choisissez vos paramÃ¨tres")
            // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
            // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexselected,
                                            boolean isChecked) {
                            itemsChecked[indexselected] = isChecked;

                            if (isChecked) {
                                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                selected_categories.add(indexselected);
                            } else if (selected_categories.contains(indexselected)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                selected_categories.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexselected));
                            }
                        }
                    })

                    // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                    // or return them to the component that opened the dialog

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

}
```

Is there a way to do it with sharedpreferences (store an arraylist) ? same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12137351/2983862) answer.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504791/2983862) is the answer with the solution and the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data as ArrayList using SharedPreferences as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Comment: I tried to follow what was in the answer..but still can't make it work.. here is my updated code : https://gist.github.com/RidouaneHicham/54c1cb3b2d326a917175 can you take a look and see if my code is ok ?

Comment: May be you do not need to save data as set, better is to save boolean array as shown in the second answer for the linked question