# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException / passing arraylist from alertdialog to activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-alertdialog, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an alertdialog with multiple choices, I store the user's choices on an ArrayList of strings, and I want to pass the stored arraylist to the host activity (I will use the array's elements to query my database)..

When i run my app, i get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (may be the index is -1..), I'm not sure if it's the loop, or if i did not pass the arraylist correctly from the alertdialog...

can you guys take a look ? here is my function :

```
    public void onOkay(ArrayList<String> selected) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (selected.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
            String categories = selected_items_array[selected.indexOf(i)];
            stringBuilder = stringBuilder.append(" " + categories);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected: "
                + stringBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

logcat :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=-1
        at com.hichamridouane.smartshop.MainActivity.onOkay(MainActivity.java:164)
        at com.hichamridouane.smartshop.TimelineSettings$2.onClick(TimelineSettings.java:71)
```

[here](https://gist.github.com/RidouaneHicham/32f79699c523fdcb0a21) is my dialogfragment class.
and [here](https://gist.github.com/RidouaneHicham/b25f2b97e5553fe1ea86) is my host activity.(as I said, i'm not sure if i'm passing correctly the arraylist to the host activity)
thanks !

Comment: What is selected_items_array ?

Comment: check both size like selected_items_array,ArrayList<String> selected

Comment: @SilentKiller it's an array of strings `private String[] selected_items_array;`

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @joao2fast4u yes I did :) I used arrays of integers in both classes. i'll post my full code asap. thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Had to use Arraylists of integers in my activity and my dialogfragment.

here is what i did in my `DialogFragment` class:

```
public class TimelineSettings extends DialogFragment {
ArrayList<Integer> selected_categories = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean[] itemsChecked = {false, false, false, false, false, false};


// this interface to communicate with the host activity.

public interface dialoglistener {
    public void onOkay(ArrayList<Integer> selected);
    public void onCancel();
}
dialoglistener mlistener;


//this function is to instantiate the dialoglistener

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mlistener = (dialoglistener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement dialogListener");
    }
}
```

My multichoice dialog :

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    for(int i=0;i<itemsChecked.length;i++){
        if(selected_categories.contains((String)String.valueOf(i)))
            itemsChecked[i]=true;
    }

    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle("Choisissez vos paramètres")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.categories, itemsChecked,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexselected,
                                            boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                if(!selected_categories.contains(indexselected)){
                                    selected_categories.add(indexselected);
                                    itemsChecked[indexselected]=true;
                                }
                            } else if (selected_categories.contains(indexselected)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                selected_categories.remove(indexselected);
                                itemsChecked[indexselected]=false;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mlistener.onOkay(selected_categories);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mlistener.onCancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

On my host activity, I implemented the fragment's interface :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* some fancy stuff */
    Resources res = getResources();
    selectedArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.categories);
}
```

Getting the selected items (and show them on a toast, just for testing) :

```
    @Override
public void onOkay(ArrayList<Integer> selected) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (selected.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
            String categories = selectedArray[selected.get(i)];
            stringBuilder = stringBuilder.append(" " + categories);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected: "
                + stringBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks really strange to me, especially in

```
String categories = selected_items_array[selected.indexOf(i)];
```

From JavaDocs about **indexOf**

```
Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element
in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.
More formally, returns the lowest index <tt>i</tt> such that
<tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>,
or -1 if there is no such index.
```

So, you try to find element in your **selected_items_array** (not correct name in Java)
in first iteration **i == 0**, **selected_items_array** have no such element => **indexOf** return **-1**. **Array** can't have element with index = -1, it starts from 0. So you have your **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

Comment: do you have an idea how to solve this ? (and yes the selected_items_array is a dumb name..was planning on changing it later)

Comment: I really misunderstand the sense of it... what are you trying to do here String categories = selected_items_array[selected.indexOf(i)]; ??

Comment: I mean, you have a collection of **Strings** (maybe it's something like "category1", "category2", etc.) and then try to find **int i** in this collection and index of it element to find another element by this index in another **Array**. It seems like wrong logic here.

Comment: yeah it's pretty messed up..passing from an arraylist to another one, then to a string[].. I will correct that and see what happens (I will use an array of integer and pass the indexes to the host activity..instead of passing the values of an array of strings)

Comment: add condition: if (selected.indexOf(i) != -1 && selected_items_array.size() >= selected.indexOf(i))